# Serial port communication and IP address

Tags: c#, winforms, serial-port

I am able to establish a serial port communication to a bacnet router.

All is well, I can change the name of the router, etc.

But when I write to the IP address:
My code:

```
serialPort1.WriteLine("10.1.1.168");
//or 
serialPort1.Write("10.1.1.168"); 
//It stores as '0.0.0.10'
```

OR:

```
serialPort1.WriteLine("145.100.100.168"); //it stores as '0.0.0.145'
```

OR:

```
serialPort1.WriteLine("145100100168"); //Im reaching lol
```

I can change, for example the router name:

```
serialPort1.WriteLine("Project1234"); //and it stores perfectly
```

I have done conversions (binary, hex, ipAddress) but it still stores a bad value.

Any ideas? Thanks for your help!!

UPDATE  - Ok this is what I have so far:

```
IPAddress ip = IPAddress.Parse(txtWrite.Text);
Byte[] bytes = ip.GetAddressBytes();
for (int i = 0; i < bytes.Length; i++)
{
    string str = bytes[i].ToString();
    MessageBox.Show(str);
    serialPort1.Write(str+".");
 }
 serialPort1.Write("\r\n");
```

But problem is if it's over 3 digits "192.168.168.5" it will not add the "." resulting in '1921681685.' (notice the decimal at the end?) BUT if I enter "10.1.1.168" it stores as '10.1.1.168' and no decimal at the end and it is what I want or needs to be for that IP address. What am I doing wrong??

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You might want to add a link to the serial protocol and the rest of your code, don't you need to send some command before the name or ipaddress?

Comment: No it is pretty simple from what I read. the connection is good and reading and writin is straight forward. it is a conversion to the IP bytes from the string that is getting wrong results. see the update. and thanks for your help.

Comment: Is there a document that explains the Bacnet commands available via the serialport?

Comment: No documentation....but it works in hyperterminal. so whatever the string of commands that are in heperterminal i should try and mimic...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all for your help. I figured it out, It's not anything to do with the type of string...it is the timing of the string being entered into the router.

```
foreach (char c in txtWrite.Text)
{
    serialPort1.WriteLine(c.ToString());
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);

 }
 serialPort1.WriteLine("\r\n");
```

And that's all.

Answer (score 1):

I guess it's not baudrate or setting related at all. It's just a thing we don't know how to specify the IP address?

In your last update, try to build an if so that the last part doesn't send an '.'.

```
IPAddress ip = IPAddress.Parse(txtWrite.Text);
Byte[] bytes = ip.GetAddressBytes();
for (int i = 0; i < bytes.Length; i++)
{
    string str = bytes[i].ToString();
    MessageBox.Show(str);
    if(i < bytes.Length - 1)//Try this out
    {
        serialPort1.Write(str+".");
    }
 }
 serialPort1.Write("\r\n");
```

Something like that. 
If I understand it, every x (in x.x.x.x) is stored in the variable bytes? I think you send a dot after the last x too, so I think that's uncommon.

Comment: Thanks. I figured it out, It's not anything to do with the type of string...it is the timing of the string being entered into the router.

Answer (score 0):

The [SerialPort-Constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.io.ports.serialport.aspx) does not know and expects [IPAdress](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.net.ipaddress.aspx)

The string parameter is **NOT** an ip adress! It is for example "COM1". That's why "Project1234" works.

Edit:

You are obviously mixing different things:

- In computing, a [serial port](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_port) is a serial communication physical interface through which information transfers in or out one bit at a time. (Wikipedia)
- In computing, a [parallel port](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_port) is a parallel communication physical interface. It is also known as a printer port or Centronics port. (Wikipedia)

**Both interfaces have absolutely nothing to do with IP adresses!**

You are talking about IP adresses, that means you want to establish a connection via [TCP/IP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Protocol) Protocol. A good start for this is: [TCP/IP Chat Application Using C#](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12893/TCP-IP-Chat-Application-Using-C)

Edit(2):
USB serial communication is indeed serial, but again it is not the serial port you try to access. For usb communication there are some libraries. [Leitner](http://www.florian-leitner.de/index.php/2007/08/03/hid-usb-driver-library/) or [SharpDevelop](http://www.icsharpcode.net/opensource/sharpusblib/)

Comment: Thanks for your input, it put me in a close direction...I think. I updated the new problem. Any iseas?

Comment: I'm afraid you may have misunderstood me. I don't want to make a connection via TCP/IP. I am connected via a USB serial port. I'm writing to a bactnet router to change values stored on the router. All I want to do is take an iP address that I create and store it in the router. If you see my last update....it will not take the parameters that I know to give.

Comment: You're giving me links to things that I don't need. I will keep investigating and post once I figure it out. Thanks for your time and energy.

Comment: He's not calling the constructor with an IP address. He sends the IP to the router, and the router should 'read' that IP-address, am I right?

Comment: Yes that is correct.  Using hyperterminal, I can change it. And my program can change all the info....if its just a string but once it gets to the IP buffer it doesn't like the string I write.....